# What should I do If I don't want to return a promise in background functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

normally I have Firestore triggers like this

```
 exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

       return db.doc("somePath").update({data:" "});
             
 });
```

but now for example I need to log the message to indicate the update process is successful, then what should I return ?

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

       await db.doc("somePath").update({data:" "});
         
       console.log("successfully update data after document creation");

       return ????? // what should I return in here?
      
 });
```

because according to [explanation from Youtube in here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk), background function (Firestore triggers in my case) should return a promise.

Comment: const updatedData = await db.doc("somePath").update({data:" "});
         
         console.log("successfully update data after document creation");

         return updatedData; // This works?

Comment: Yep as @SyedMohibUddin has it. The `async` handler returns a promise always, so just returning a value there will return a promise wrapping that value.

Comment: @msbit is totally right, the `async` handler always returns a promise, so returning any value is fine, like `return null;` or `return 1;`. @msbit you may write an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `return` is fine, so:

```
return true;
```

Or:

```
return null;
```

Or even simply:

```
return;
```

That last one essentially makes your function return type a `Promise<void>`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `async` functions you need to return a Promise, so you have two options:

**Option 1: Return a resolved Promise**

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

       await db.doc("somePath").update({data:" "});

       console.log("successfully update data after document creation");

       return Promise.resolve();
      
 });
```

**Option 2: Simplest solution without `async`**

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
       return db.doc("somePath").update({data:" "});
    });
```